# Picking up localized checkboxes for a 'select all' with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

My aim to pick up local checkboxes in a very massive form, so I'll need markers to grab those inputs for each checkbox within a region. One of the issues is that I cannot seem to pick up the checkboxes. I'm using JSfiddle to give an idea and my HTML is the following - cut down for only one checkbox for a simple test.

HTML:

```
    <div class="DoAll">
    <div class="span5">
        <li class="option table">
            <div class="cell" id="left">
                <div class="icon options">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" id="center">
                <div class="option-text">
                    Unemployed
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell" id="right">
                <div class="option-checkbox">
                    <div class="check">
                    </div>
                    <input id="id_MyJobChoices_18" name="MyJobChoices" type="checkbox" value="_UM" /><label
                        for="id_MyJobChoices_18"><span></span></label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span5 mar-left">
    <li class="option table">
        <div class="cell" id="left">
            <div class="icon options">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell" id="center">
            <div class="option-text">
                Select All</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell" id="right">
            <div class="option-checkbox">
                <div class="check">
                </div>
                <input id="select_All" type="checkbox" value="select_All"><label for="select_All"><span></span></label></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#select_All').click(function(e){     
    $(this)
      .closest('DoAll')
      .find('checkbox')
      .prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

However this doesn't work. I have checked that the function is fired on checking the Select All box, but how can I pick up the checkboxes that are located within the DIV tag: **DoAll**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your html is not well formed, there is one too many div-ending at the end.

Then your selector "DoAll" is not right, if you want to search by css class, you have to use ".DoAll". Though you have another problem here. The div ".DoAll" is not parent of the "#select_All"-input, so the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)-function does not find anything.

Also the "checkbox"-selector should be [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

What you want to do might be something like

```
$('#select_All').on("click" ,function() {
    $(".DoAll :checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see this working for a single option i.e. a series of checkboxes, but how in one form do I deal with multiple banks of checkboxes each with their own selectAll?

Comment: Then you need to have same parent for the selectAll-button and the checkboxes you want to select. Then you can use the closest-function to search the parent and find-function to find the checkboxes in that parent. Of course you cannot use "#select_All" id for this since ids have to be unique, use a class instead and add that class to each of the selectall-buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#select_All').click(function(e){
    $(".DoAll").find('input').prop('checked', true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4mBPN/

Answer (score 1):

- `select_All` is not inside `DoAll`, so `closest` can't find it. `closest` only looks at the current node's ancestors.
- `DoAll` is a class. The correct selector is `.DoAll`.
- `find('checkbox')` doesn't work because `checkbox` is not a tag name. `input` is the tag you want.

Try this:

```
$('#select_All').click(function(e) {
    $('.DoAll').find('input').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```